# Does 'Status' field update on ServiceContract object triggers a trigger?

Tags: apex, trigger

The field 'Status' on ServiceContract  is updated automatically with the statuses 'Inactive'/'Active'/'Expired'  depending on the EndDate and StartDate.
'Status' field is a picklist field, not a formula. Hence the question - will this field update(done by SF automatically) trigger a SC trigger?
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

I dont think it will not execute a trigger while updating the Status field automatically based on Start and EndDates.

I have checked this in my personal Org. The lastModifiedDate it self is not updating and checked for Trigger  call as well and did not find any trace of it.

Comment: sadly, the [reference on operations that don't fire triggers](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_ignoring_operations.htm) is incomplete. You should submit a doc feedback item for this one

Comment: Sure @cropredy, I will check this internally and get this updated

Comment: @SaiPraveenKakkirala Your comment is not clear to me. I am also encountering the same problem. Will it execute trigger when current date exceeds end date?

Comment: @doga, This will not execute the trigger .